# Why does CSS linking certain fragment-identifier & #svgView(viewBox()) SVG sprites not work properly in Chrome and FF?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, svg

According https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-fragment claims Chrome has been able to use SVG fragment identifiers in CSS since chrome 50, but this doesn't seem to work properly for all cases.

It seems to work fine for cases like [this example](https://codepen.io/rgba/pen/EZbVLR) which uses an SVG with

```
<symbol id="arrow">
    <polyline points="41.5,67 58.5,50 41.5,33"/>
</symbol>
```

But then I saw [this case](https://www.broken-links.com/tests/svg/fragment-identifiers.php) that doesn't work properly as of Chrome 63. It uses an SVG with:

```
<view id="devil-view" viewBox="0 45 48 40"/>
```

Firefox displays the "As background-image with CSS #ID" one ok, but it too fails to restrict the view of the "As background-image with svgView" one.

For a moment I thought the problem might be that Chrome doesn't support CSS targeting SVGs with VIEW elements and both Chrome and FF don't support CSS using #svgView(viewBox()), but then I saw [another example](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/GndhE) where not only does does a VIEW-element-targeting work, even background-image with #svgView(viewBox()) works for both.

The problem seems to be that if background-sizes aren't set, the browsers don't seem to reflect the viewbox parameters. In the broken monkey and devil example, if you set background-size to 100%, it fixes the problem there.

I haven't found discussion of this elsewhere, and yet it seems like something that must come up, so I'm confused. Is this genrally known as an area of undefined behavior?

How would one handle it for cases where you want a repeating background,
 or don't know whether the aspect ratio of your background will match up to the viewbox defined in the SVG? ([See this example](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldc3b4ut/).)

Aside from CSS, I notice that some SVGs, opened in they're own tab, like https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/Test/20011026/linking-view-BE-04.svg#circle-view restrict the view as one would expect, while other things like https://betravis.github.io/icon-methods/resources/bunny-sprite-sheet.svg#carrot-bunny don't. Perhaps a fault in the way certain SVGs are constructed is causing that, and could that be the answer to the CSS linking issue too? Because [this CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/L20xufo7/) using that w3 SVG *does* work.

Comment: If you don't set an image size then the image size is..... undefined. So set one.

Comment: That doesn't actually fully explain why it works for some SVGs and not others. Take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/797kvdL3/ in Chrome and FF. In Chrome: The img Element and the DIV css background-image get their centering from the VIEW element's viewbox attribute, but use an aspect ratio according to the SVG element's viewbox attribute. CSS properties that are undefined are undefined of course, but it turns out this isn't limited to CSS; the browser are differing on how to regard the content's own aspect ratio. FF takes the aspect ratio from the VIEW element's viewbox attribute.

Comment: I can only comment on what the SVG spec says and what Firefox does, what non-Chrome issues are you confused about that don't involve images without width or height? The view element should provide the aspect ratio for instance, which is what I implemented in Firefox.

Comment: FF supports using #svgView(viewBox(..)) in background-image URL, no? How come in https://www.broken-links.com/tests/svg/fragment-identifiers.php , for the second test the CSS background-image: url('../images/faces.svg#svgView(viewBox(0,45,48,40))'); succeeds in *centering* the view on the point x=0+(.5*48), y=45+(.5*40), in accordance with the viewbox override numbers explicitly set in the URL, but for area it's still using the 48x86 dimensions set by the svg file's <svg .... viewBox="0 0 48 86">? Shouldn't the URL-set viewBox be overriding that entirely?

Comment: ...Moreover the same thing would happen in the fourth example labeled "As img with svgView" if you delete the height="40" HTML attribute from the IMG tag. Again, FF registers that you're recentering it with the URL-declared viewBox, but it's still obeying the viewBox set in the SVG file to determine dimensions, so things just get shifted up a bit, rather than actually taking on a 48:40 aspect ratio.